# Standard C++ function object template for the subscript operator

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I currently have a template function like this:

```
template <class T, class K>
void* get_subobject(K key)
{
  T& obj = function_returning_T_ref<T>();

  // do various other things...

  return &obj[key];
}
```

And I would like to make the subscript operation configurable so that the user could apply their own code to map `obj` and `key` to the return value.  Something like this:

```
template <class T, class K, class Op = subscript<T, K>>
void* get_subobject(K key)
{
  T& obj = function_returning_T_ref<T>();

  // do various other things...

  return &Op{}(obj, key);
}
```

My question is, for the default template parameter `subscript<T,K>` above is there a standard template (along the lines of `std::less<T>`) that I can use here so that `Op` defaults to calling `operator[]`?  I can't see anything appropriate in `<functional>`.

If there is no standard template for this, am I best to create my own or is there some way I can use `std::bind()` or similar to the same effect without additional overhead?

Comment: Since an answer has already been given, I would suggest making a default `Op` parameter: `get_subobject(K key, Op op = Op())`. This way you can just do `return &op(obj, key)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in template, but it's not too hard to create your own (that, once inlined, will have no overhead):

```
template<typename T, typename K>
struct subscript
{
    inline auto operator()(T const& obj, K const& key) const -> decltype(obj[key])
    {
        return obj[key];
    }

    inline auto operator()(T& obj, K const& key) const -> decltype(obj[key])
    {
        return obj[key];
    }
};
```

You could even have one that worked on implicit types (I like this one best):

```
struct subscript
{
    template<typename T, typename K>
    inline auto operator()(T&& obj, K&& key) const
        -> decltype(std::forward<T>(obj)[std::forward<K>(key)])
    {
        return std::forward<T>(obj)[std::forward<K>(key)];
    }
};
```

The user, of course, can pass in any conforming type of their own, including a `std::function` object or plain function pointers.

Comment: What does `inline` do here?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Probably nothing :-) But I like to be explicit with my inline hints.